# How to select one column value, normalize and put to another column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update

In my table, I've got a column call **mobile** and I need this **mobile** field value to be normalized and save to another column call **formatted_phone**. For this purpose, I am using the below MySQL query and unfortunately, it is not working. I am putting my query here, please someone correct it. Thank you.

```
UPDATE hiring_detail
SET formatted_phone = replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(mobile,'-',''),'+',''),')',''),'(',''),' ',''),'.','')
WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL;
```

Error what it throws:

```
SQL Error (1265):Data truncated for column 'formatted_phone' at row 3
```

mobile column: varchar 50
formatted_phone: bigint 15

Comment: I think that one REGEXP_REPLACE() will be faster than 6 nested REPLACE(). *it is not working* What does this words means precisely?

Comment: when you say it is not working? what do you see?

Comment: it does not say any error in the query, it just says truncated :/

Comment: What is the length of the `formatted_phone` column then? If it is less than `mobile` then that response makes sense.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I've updated the question with the error and column data type and length. please check. thank you.

Comment: *formatted_phone: bigint 15* The length specification for integer datatypes is deprecated. Remove it, use `BIGINT` only. *SQL Error (1265):Data truncated for column 'formatted_phone' at row 3* - check the value for this row, maybe it really contains too many chars (including ones which are not replaced with your code, for example, tabular, non-breaking space, etc.)

Comment: Test `UPDATE hiring_detail SET formatted_phone = REGEXP_REPLACE(mobile,'[^0-9]','') + 0 WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, beofre blindly executing `UPDATE` commands, we do a simply *What If* analysis first, just run the query as a `SELECT` so you can inspect the output and importantly, you can compare it to the existing values:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47723a/2

```
SELECT mobile, formatted_phone
, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(mobile,'-',''),'+',''),')',''),'(',''),' ',''),'.','') as test
FROM hiring_detail
WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL;
```

If that logic works for you (and it does in my tests) then there should be no issue with your `UPDATE` logic.

### UPDATE:

If your error is

> SQL Error (1265):Data truncated for column 'formatted_phone' at row 3

Then that means that your formatted phone numbers are longer than the column width for `formatted_phone`. If you know what the length is, you can truncate your formatted numbers, but with phone numbers, if we remove the actual number, this usually results in phone numbers that cannot be called.

I would recommend instead that you increase the width of the `formatted_phone` field.

This is an example of a forced truncation:

```
UPDATE hiring_detail
SET formatted_phone = RIGHT(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(mobile,'-',''),'+',''),')',''),'(',''),' ',''),'.',''),10)
WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL;
```

## Update #2

given that the column is an int, we need to convert the value into an integer.

```
UPDATE hiring_detail
SET formatted_phone = CAST(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(mobile,'-',''),'+',''),')',''),'(',''),' ',''),'.','') as UNSIGNED INT)
WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL;
```

> **Warning:** It is NOT advisable to store phone numbers as integers, the leading zeros can be significant in area codes in many localities, by storing as a numeric value this can have significant effects and can result in los of data. It also makes it hard to search for partial matches on the numbers. Almost all operations that you can think of (including sorting) on phone numbers will involve string manipulations, not mathematical or numerical.